# native library missing error in Bluetooth Server

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluecove

When I try to run Bluetooth server, I got this error.

I'm using Windows7 64 bit, i5 system.

```
C:\Bluetooth Server>java BluetoothServer
Native Library intelbth not available
Native Library bluecove not available
Exceptionjavax.bluetooth.BluetoothStateException: BlueCove not available
```

How can I overcome this error?

Answer (score 0):

bluecove needs a native library, check if it's available( I'm not a Windows man, but I remember it has to reside in system32 or something similar)